# Send SNS notification to all Users that subscribed the topic from Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have created an E-Commerce IOS app with backend in nodejs **(AWS Lambda)**. When a user signedIn/LoggedIn, the app subscribes a **SNS Topic** which I have created to send notifications and stores the **push token and device ARN** in DB.
Now I want to send push notification to all users who have subscribed that SNS Topic, when we added a new item to the store.
Currently, to send notification I am fetching all users from DB and loop through the users to get their push token and send notification to users one by one, which is very costly process, and the API took too much time.

**Now I want to do is to hit the SNS topic from Lambda and pass the body of notification to that topic and that SNS topic will send notification to all users who have subscribed the Topic**.
I have searched it but can't find any solution.

The code I have done to send notification is

```
await Promise.all(targetArns.map(async (item, index) => {
         const publishNotificationParams = { 
            "TargetArn": item,
            "Message": JSON.stringify({
              "default": JSON.stringify({
                  "category" : title,
                  "alert" : {
                    "title" : title,
                    "body" : 'New product is launced',
                    "data" : product
                  },
                  "badge" : 1,
                  "sound" : "chime.aiff"
                }),
                "APNS_SANDBOX": JSON.stringify(params),
                "APNS": JSON.stringify(params)
            }),
            "MessageStructure": "json"
        };
        var publishTextPromise = sns.publish(publishNotificationParams).promise();
       publishTextPromise.then(
        function(data) {
          console.log(`Message ${publishNotificationParams.Message} sent to the topic ${publishNotificationParams.TargetArn}`);
        }).catch(
          function(err) {
          console.error(err, err.stack);
        });
     }));
```

But for this I have to fetch every user from DB get their endpoint ARN and then send notification by iteration.

I want to call SNS topic pass the body of notification and SNS will send notification to every user that has subscribed that SNS topic.

I am doing this because I want to save the cost to fetch every users from DB and then send notification

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-custom-platform-specific-payloads-mobile-devices.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @hoangdv I have read this before but can't find the solution I want.

Comment: That is **send notification to all users of a topic from lambda**

Comment: So, what is your problem?

Comment: I have updated my question where I have implemented my code to send notification to users one by one through iteration after fetching the users from DB. I dont want to fetch users from DB to get their endpoint ARN from there. instead I want is that I directly call SNS topic and that send notification to users.

Comment: @noorshafique Nice idea, what did you try?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/example_sns_Publish_section.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could achieve that flow. I think you already have some parts of this implemented.

1. Create a topic that will be used to fan out the notification to all of your users: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_CreateTopic.html
2. Create platform application(s) for the different platforms your app is used on: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_CreatePlatformApplication.html
3. When a user signs up for your app, create a platform endpoint for the application corresponding to the user's platform: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_CreatePlatformEndpoint.html

   3.1. If you want to be able to target this user directly, also store this ARN somewhere for direct publishes (as you are doing now).
4. Now also create a subscription for the topic created in step 1 to the endpoint ARN: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html
5. Publish to the topic created during step 1: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html

SNS will automatically fan out the message to all subscribers (all of your users), so each of them will receive a notification without you iterating over each user.

Comment: **Things I have achieved so far** :
IOS  and Andriod users have subscribed their SNS topic respectively.
Basic API in Lambda function created

**Now the thing  I want is** that API/Lambda gets input as string and send that string to both SNS topics.
I have created the Lambda function but unable to call SNS topic from Lambda to send notifications to all users with iterating.